# WebGL fragment shader opacity

Tags: javascript, webgl, glsl, shader

Alright, first off, I'm pretty new at GLSL shaders, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the following shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    //precision mediump float;
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    uniform vec2 uTimes;

    varying vec2 texCoord;
    varying vec2 screenCoord;

    void main(void) {
        vec3 col;
        float c;
        vec2 tmpv = texCoord * vec2(0.8, 1.0) - vec2(0.95, 1.0);
        c = exp(-pow(length(tmpv) * 1.8, 2.0));
        col = mix(vec3(0.02, 0.0, 0.03), vec3(0.96, 0.98, 1.0) * 1.5, c);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(col * 0.5, 0);
    }
```

So far, I know it gives me a radial gradient (perhaps). What I'd really like to know is how to make it completely transparent. I'm thinking that I need a vec4 for that, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to turn on the blending.

See http://www.senchalabs.org/philogl/PhiloGL/examples/lessons/8/ and http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=859‎.

Without blending, depth and color buffers will be updated without taking care what was previously in the buffer, it will just overwrite data. With blending on, and depending on what type of blending function are you using, buffers will be updated with data that takes previsouly rendered data into a count.

This is the part that is interesting for you:

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it worked. Somewhat. That shader represents the background. I can make it transparent, however I've hit another wall. I can't make the canvas' background transparent, even with Blend or vec4(0,0,0,0). I have a background-image on the body, but the canvas is all black.

Comment: Render background image also on canvas. Just simple, whole-space-filling quad. Please accept answer if resolved your problem from question, another problem is yet another question.

Comment: Is there any reason why this fixes my Alpha issues in Chrome, but now nothings visible in Firefox, whereas before i added this it worked in firefox but not in chrome? :/

Comment: Turns out Fire just blends it a lot more aggressively - So an alpha of .3 in Chrome is equal to .8 in Firefox..