# How to render objects without blending with transparency enabled in webgl

Tags: javascript, html, css, webgl

I am trying to render two objects, with two separate `gl.drawArrays` call. I want to have transparent parts of the objects not be visible. Also I want to render one object on top of another so the first drawn object is not visible where it overlaps the second one.

I use this setup on my render loop:

```
 gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439897/webgl-fragment-shader-opacity
 gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
 gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
 gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

I am not sure what the blend functions do but I use them so the transparency is enabled. But that causes two objects to blend and create a yellow colour. (One object is red, other is green). I want to have red if i draw red last, and vice versa, while having transparency enabled.

```js
const fShaderSource2 = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

`;


const fShaderSource = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  outColor = texture(u_texture, vec2(0.0));
}

`;

const vShaderSource = `#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec2 a_position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
}
`;

main(document.getElementById('app'));

function main(element) {
  
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  element.append(canvas);
  const displayWidth = canvas.clientWidth,
        displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = displayWidth;
  canvas.height = displayHeight;


  let graphics = new Graphics({width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight}, gl);
  
  new Loop(() => {
     graphics.render();
  }).start();
}

function Graphics(state, gl) {

  const { width, height } = state;

  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  
  
  let minibatch = [];
  
  const redText = makeGlQuad(gl, fShaderSource, canvasTexture());
  const greenText = makeGlQuad(gl, fShaderSource2);

  this.render = () => {  
  
    minibatch.push(redText);
    minibatch.push(greenText);
    
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    minibatch.forEach(({
      program,
      resUniformLocation,
      vao,
      glTexture
    }) => {

    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.uniform2f(resUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    
    if (glTexture) {
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, glTexture);
    }
    
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  });
  minibatch = [];
  };

}

function makeGlQuad(gl, fShaderSource, texture) {

  let vShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderSource);
  let fShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderSource);

  let program = createProgram(gl, vShader, fShader);

  let posAttrLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  let posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuffer);


  /*
    (-1, 1).( 1, 1)
        .
    (-1,-1).( 1,-1)
   */
  let positions = [
    -1, 1,
    -1, -1,
    1, -1,
    -1, 1,
    1,-1,
    1, 1
  ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


  let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posAttrLocation);

  let size = 2,
      type = gl.FLOAT,
      normalize = false,
      stride = 0,
      offset = 0;

  gl.vertexAttribPointer(posAttrLocation,
                         size,
                         type,
                         normalize,
                         stride,
                         offset);

  let glTexture;
  if (texture) {
    glTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, glTexture);
  
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
    //gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));


    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  }



  let resUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  let texUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");
 
 
  return {
   program,
   resUniformLocation,
   vao,
   glTexture
  }
}

function canvasTexture() {
 
 return withCanvasTexture(256, 256, (w, h, canvas, ctx) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.font = '50pt Comic Sans';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.fillText('label', w / 2, 50);

    return canvas;
 });
 
function withCanvasTexture(width, height, f) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  f(width, height, canvas, canvas.getContext('2d'));
  const texture = canvas;
  //document.body.append(canvas);
  return texture;
}
}

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
  let shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  let success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);

  if (success) {
    return shader;
  }

  console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
  return null;
};

function createProgram(gl, vShader, fShader) {
  let program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  let success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (success) {
    return program;
  }

  console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
  return null;
}


// Loop Library
function Loop(fn) {

const perf = window.performance !== undefined ? window.performance : Date;

const now = () => perf.now();

const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame;

  let running = false,
      lastUpdate = now(),
      frame = 0;

  this.start = () => {
    if (running) {
      return this;
    }

    running = true;
    lastUpdate = now();
    frame = raf(tick);
    return this;
  };

  this.stop = () => {
    running = false;

    if (frame != 0) {
      raf.cancel(frame);
    }

    frame = 0;
    return this;
  };

  const tick = () => {
    frame = raf(tick);
    const time = now();
    const dt = time - lastUpdate;
    fn(dt);
    lastUpdate = time;
  };
}
```

```css
#app canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;

  width: 100vmin;
  height: 70vmin;

  transform: translate(-50%, -25%);

  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  cursor: none;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```

You can see here:

```
minibatch.push(redText);
minibatch.push(greenText);
```

I render red first and then green second but I get yellow instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use the wrong blend function ([`blendFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.3)). Blending defines a function which combines the fragment color outputs with the current colors in the color buffers. The fist parameter is the factor for the fragment color output and the 2nd parameter the factor for the color in the color buffer. The colors are summed, because the default blend equation (`blendEquation()`) is `FUNC_ADD`.

So the blend function

> ```js
> gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
> ```

can be expressed by the formula

```
destColor = srcColor * srcAlpha + destColor * 1
```

where `destColor` is the current color in the framebuffer, `srcColor` is the color which is set to fragment (`outColor`).
This causes that the color in the current framebuffer is kept (multiplied by 1). The new color is multiplied by the alpha channel and add to the color in the framebuffer. If the color in the framebuffer is red (1, 0, 0) and the new color is green (0, 1, 0), then the result is yellow (if the alpha channel is 1):

```
(0, 1, 0) * 1 + (1, 0, 0) * 1 == (1, 1, 0)
```

Use the blend function :

```js
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

which cause that the color in the frambuffer and the new color are "mixed", dependent on the alpha channel of the new color:

```
destColor = srcColor * srcAlpha + destColor * (1-srcAlpha)
```

The general principle of [Alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) is similar as in OpenGL (since WebGL (2.0) conforms closely to the OpenGL ES (3.0)), so further information can be found at the OpenGL wiki page [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending).

Comment: When I do that, I lose the first object drawn if second object's alpha is zero: https://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/128merwn/26/

Comment: @eguneys Sorry, stupid fault. The name of the enumerator constant is `ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` rather than `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`